# CPU monitoring software - Windows

Tags: windows, system-monitor

Is there any Windows software available which monitors the CPU usage of the system & records it (keep logs of the monitoring)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are a ton of software packages for that – but we have no idea which of those you might like: your question is much too broad, we need more details. Please see: [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little open with regards to detail. You have set little to no requirements such as free\paid, open source etc. so I will answer this the best I can. Yes - there are a number of tools you can use.

Option 1 - DIY

Through an elevated command prompt you can run the following:

```
typeperf "\processor(_total)\% processor time" && wmic cpu get loadpercentage
```

Then simply output the data to a csv or text file. Using `>>Output.txt` would be sufficient.

Option 2 - Open Hardware monitor

Monitoring of CPU and outputting data can be performed via: [Open hardware monitor](http://openhardwaremonitor.org/). This is a good option for a free monitoring solution to a PC. If you want to know more about what it monitors before downloading [check here.](http://openhardwaremonitor.org/screenshots/)

Option 3 -  CPU ID

CPU ID is probably the more well known tool. This software can monitor your PC and export it into a csv file per monitor - i.e. CPU_Core1_Thread1_Heat or CPU_Core1_Usage.

This tool is free for use and can be downloaded [here](http://www.cpuid.com/).

Lastly do some research and review the tools in this [here](http://listoffreeware.com/best-free-cpu-temperature-monitor-software-windows/).

If there is any particular feature you're chasing let me know and I will investigate for you. If you feel as though I have answered this, mark it so.

Comment: Excellent!! Thanks for your suggestions. I will take a look for all these softwares.

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava No worries. Personally I use Hardware Monitor which gives me the list of all things for CPU, GPU etc. It allows me to export in CSV format. I have another excel spreadsheet that then grabs the data and populates it into visual graphs and reports. Please note I may have misguided you with CPU ID as it is a side dev of the HWInfo. This is available on the same link.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I will look for Hardware Monitor. It seems it suits my needs.